# make a linux based scheduling function in c++2a standard

Tags: c++, scheduled-tasks, c++20

I have a function that continiously checks if a job needs to be scheduled... When a job does need to be scheduled, I want to be able to call the function like so: `scheduler.schedule(function(arg of function), timestamp of when to run it))` This means that the function doesnt need to be ran as soon as its scheduled, but it will be given an EPOCH UNIX timestamp to know when to run it after scheduling.

```
while (sublist.size() - 1 > checked) {
    std::vector<std::string> u_time_split = Misc::split_string(sublist[checked]);

    /* if the timestamp is greater than 5 minutes away, schedule a thread with the timestamp */
    int epoch = time(0);

    if (std::stoi(u_time_split[1]) - epoch < 2) {
       std::cout << "Scheduling Thread to run using this: " << u_time_split[0] << " | When to run: " << Misc::epoch_to_utc(u_time_split[1]) << std::endl;

       schedule here
    }

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5))
}
```

The main loop is this. 
When a function that needs to be run is given to the scheduler, one thread should run it. How would I go about achieving this?

Comment: Set up a multimap, keyed by starting time, so the next job to run will always be the first value in the map, and then wait until it's time comes or another function gets added, which can end up being executed first?

Comment: What do you mean with "linux based"? What have you tried, what actual issues do you face?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt i just mean its on a linux based system, stated so theres no confusion about os

Comment: @SamVarshavchik okay, once i have a job in the multimap, how would i check when it needs to be ran, i mean the timestamp would be in the map but would i have 1 other thread checking when the multimap functions/jobs need to be ran? if so, would i just implement a thread pool then start a thread on the function?

Comment: @samv I think 6 is enough.  But they are short, and require the reader do homework.

Answer (score 1):

Maintain a priority queue of tasks to run and one or more threads in a task running pool.

Guard the priority queue with a mutrx and a condition variable.

When a task is submitted that moves the front of the priority queue up, kick the condition variable with a notification to wake up the worker thread(s).

The worker thread(s) sleep for a timeout, or for the front of the queue's scheduled time "moving up", on the condition variable.  If they wake up they check if the front of the queue is scheduled to run; if so, they do so.  If not, they check if they need to update their timeout, and do so if needed.

It is a bit tricky to get it to work.  I'd advise practicing by making a non-schedualing thread pool first.

The worker and submitting thread can be the same thread if you write it correctly.